# UIViewController push UITabbarController and push UivewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

my iOS app flow like UIViewController -----> UITabbarController having two view--->UIViewController1 and UIViewController2 -------after that UIViewController2--------->UIViewController3

Comment: What exactly is the question here? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Embed first UIViewController in navigation VC . Also add tab navigations in separate Navigation Controller if you want to have tabbar in UIViewController 3.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, You can do it also programatically
Here are the steps: 
Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
In your ViewController.h 
 Set action here for **Go to tabbar** button

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)gotoTab:(id)sender;

@end
```

In your ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}



- (IBAction)gotoTab:(id)sender {

    FirstViewController*  viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    SecondViewController*  viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"View1" image:Nil tag:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"View2" image:Nil tag:2];

    UINavigationController *navigate, *navigate2;

    navigate = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    navigate2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    navigate.tabBarItem = item;
    navigate2.tabBarItem = item2;
    UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init ];

     tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigate,navigate2, nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];


}
@end
```

Step 3:
Create three viewcontrollers with xib file

[image]

Set the xib files for FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController as follows
[image]

[image]

[image]

Step 4:
Set action for **go to thirdview** button 
In SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)gothird:(id)sender;

@end
```

In SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)gothird:(id)sender {

    ThirdViewController *third = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:third animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: i want without storyboard, programmatically how's that achieve

Comment: Hope every steps are clear and will help you, you can set image for tabbaritems, i set here nil. Thanks